# Trouble with click not unbinding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a small adventure to help me understand some concepts of JQuery/Javascript and I've hit a snag.

What I'm trying to do is by clicking on a "take" button and then on an item on the screen to move it to the inventory. Good news is, that all works. Bad news is that if I press another item without using the "take" button first it goes straight to my inventory.

Same problem with "look". You should have to press "look" first and then the item to get a description, but once it's pressed it'll give every item you click a description straight away.

You can imagine that once you've pressed them both every item you click without clicking another button will give you a description and end up in your inventory straight away.

This is how I'm trying to get it to unbind:

```
$("#take").click(function () {
    $("#zilverenKogel").click(function () {
        $("#zilverenKogel").fadeOut(1200, 0);
        $("#invKogel").fadeTo(1500, 1);
        $("#take").unbind("click");
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Mofx solved it for me. End, and working result, is:

```
 var state = null;
$( "#take" ).click(function () {state = "take";})
$( "#look" ).click(function () {state = "look";})


$( "#zilverenKogel" ).click(function () {
    if (state == "take") {
        $("#zilverenKogel").fadeOut(1200, 0);
        $("#invKogel").fadeTo(1500, 1);
      state=null;
    } else if (state == "look") {
        alert("blablabla");
       state=null;
    }

});
```

thanks a lot Mofx!

Comment: And this doesn't unbind ? Do you have errors in the console ?

Comment: Have you tried to use on and off functions?

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kQQ3x/1/

Comment: dystroy - No errors in the console

Comment: red_alert - No. I'm really still rather wet behind my ears :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You unbind the wrong event. You want to unbind the event on "#zilverenKogel", because that is the one doing the "take-action".

I also suspect, you connect events to other elements as well within "$("#take").click(function () {". You would have to disconnect them all. After the action was taken or another action was selected.

Maybe a statemachine would be a better solution here. Something like:

```
var state = null;
$("#take").click(function () {state = "take";}
$("#look").click(function () {state = "look";}

$("#zilverenKogel").click(function () {
  if (state == "take") {
    moveToInventory();
  } else if (state == "look") {
    showDescription();
  }
}
```

Comment: Using states *is* usually the way to go, it's saner than binding and unbinding, +1 for that.

Comment: Ah yes, that could very well be the reason it didn't work when I just changed #zilverenKogel.

Comment: That state solution looks like a much better idea. I'm going to implement that and see if I can get it working. Will let you know how that worked out for me.

Comment: Ok, implented it and it's the much more eloquent solution compared to what I was doing. So thanks a lot for that! Problem remains the same though. If I click look and then one item I don't have to click look again to get the description for that item or any other item.

Comment: So set state = null after you executed any action

Comment: Hi Mofx, sorry to take so much of your time, edited my original post with two ways I tried to put state = null in there, both failed miserably.

Comment: The problem is the "var" in front of "state = null".
This creates a NEW locale variable state, but you have to set the previously defined state variable. Take a look at JavaScript scopes to really understand this

Comment: Yes of course. I am an idiot and it is working now. Thanks so much for your time and patience!